# How to overlay one div in the middle of 2 divs

Tags: html, css, overlay

I have a div

```
<div id="showMore">
```

and I can overlay it over the background like so

```
#showMore {
width: 100%;
height: '69.9%; */ I had to cut the bottom of, so that I can reach player buttons */
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
background': rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
font-size: 450%;
}
```

but the problem is that I have one more div that is then overlayed and I cannot click its button

```
<div id="audio-container">
```

so I want to overlay `<div id="showMore">` over `body` but not over `<div id="audio-container">`

**UPDATED TO INCLUDE EXAMPLE**
Example here: https://jsfiddle.net/rcdnzabf/ (as you can see Overlayed text should overlay some random text, but not TEST button)

Comment: Please include a code example of the problem in the question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
body {
  font-family: system-ui;
  background: #f06d06;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  margin:0;
}
.bgimage{
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/1324803/pexels-photo-1324803.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=3&h=750&w=1260) no-repeat center;
}
.overlay{
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  z-index:1;
  background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
h1{
  position:relative;
  z-index:2;
}
```

```html
<div class="bgimage">
</div>
<div class="overlay">
</div>
<h1>Title Goes Here</h1>
```

You can manage div step up and down position using z-index css. Please check Above live demo.

Comment: You should add your code example to your answer. This will help preserve the answer if the codepen is removed. Additionally, your link is not formatted correctly, so it is not clickable.

Comment: setting position: absolute on the div I wanted to overlay did it, thank you

Answer (score -4):

check following code :

```
<div>
    <div id="showMore">
    
    </div>
   
    <div id="audio-container">

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not enough information to be helpful. You should add more explanation.